# Jerks on 2nd gear at low speed

Tags: engine, transmission, suzuki, swift

My car jerks on second gear when I slow down while on second gear and then want to accelerate back. After changing the plugs and air filter it got a bit better but after driving 500+ miles it is back to the same point.

It is a manual transmission carburetor  Suzuki Swift 1996, the saloon model. The idle RPM is set to 0.7 to 0.9k. Got the butterfly valve repaired as well (I think this is responsible for uneven gas intake?).

***Failing to understand, what could cause this?***

**EDIT:**

Explaining the jerks:

It jerks like sudden continuous thrusts, no knocking sound from engine like when you under gear. The more I press the gas the more jerky it gets, so i release the gas, press the clutch and then time them both to accelerate, as what you do in a pick-up while starting off the car from stop in first gear.

Comment: The car jerks once heavily, or the engine starts stuttering for a second or two when you press gas before accelerating away?

Comment: Engine mounts could be worn.

Comment: Can you explain what 'jerks on second gear' means a little bit more deeply?

Comment: Sounds like a misfire. If your plugs, plug wires and distributor (if used) are fine then your mixture isn't good. I'd guess a bad vacuum leak.

Comment: What RPM are you at when it starts jerking?  I am wondering if this might be gear lash.  This isn't something that would be repaired with plugs and an air filter though and should get better once you hit the gas and put a constant load on the drivetrain.

Comment: @rpmerf I believe that would cause a single jerk. If it jerks multiple times after switching gear and gets worse with throttle then it definitely sounds like problems igniting the mixture at load.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't really understand but the jerking seems to have been fixed up to 90% after I changed the gear oil. For more details, see [here](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/25788/weird-grinding-sound-from-the-gear-box/25829#25829).

Comment: You can award yourself the answer for a badge   :-)