# Weird grinding sound from the gear box

Tags: transmission

It is not like when you try to shift a manual stick without the clutch. But a lot lighter than that varying in amplitude (louder and lower) and probably is only there when the engine is cold (Because I don't seem to observe it after I have driven a few miles).

**How I confirmed?**
On neutral gear, I paddled the gas the sound goes louder but when I press the clutch and then paddle there is no sound.

So does it call for a gear box repair?

PS: and yes I could observe this back when I used to turn the A/C on, back then the sound was very low and when I would press the clutch it would disappear.

If this is a gear box repair thing can I delay it? or it would cause nine stitches later on?

Comment: Have you checked/changed the gearbox oil?

Comment: yes changed the oil 6 months (5000 miles back) but then also the sound was was still there but it was very low, it was only there when I turned on A/C

Comment: @HandyHowie yes now changed it and the sound is gone, I was wondering how could such loud noise just vanish with just oil changing. This kept me from thinking wheather it was a mere oil issue. The quantity drained of the oil was about 2 liters and the mechanic poured in 3.

Comment: If the transmission was low on oil, then some of the gears will not be submerged in the oil.  Hopefully the gears will have still been getting splashed with oil to keep them lubricated.  I guess when submerged in the oil, the oil will stop/absorb the noise of the gears meshing with each other.  Either you have an oil leak or enough oil wasn't added last time.  I guess you need to keep checking the oil for a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the sound goes away when the clutch is depressed then the sound is coming from the rotating internals of the gearbox, depressing the clutch will allow them to come to a stop (bear in mind that it's a constant-mesh box, so if the clutch is up then the internals spin even in neutral when the car is stationary)

The best diagnosis is to drain the gearbox oil, it should be clear and a light caramel colour, if there is evidence of metal filings then the box is worn or worse.

This is also a good opportunity to refresh the oil and make sure that the oil level is correct, which can both have a positive effect on gearbox performance, life and noise.

It looks as though you're concerned about cost, and oil change is inexpensive compared to the cost of gearbox repair, especially if you can do it yourself.

Comment: Changing the gear oil fixed the sound, its absolutely gone, how long does the gear oil last? I mean when do you have to change it?

Comment: couldn't observe traces of metal filings, it was dark and I dint feel like putting my hand in to find any pieces, they weren't observed with naked eye